# App icon not shown in Safari in the share menu opened by a long press on a link

Tags: ios, safari, ios10, ios-app-extension

My app has an extension. This extension is available in Safari. When I use Safari share button

[image]

then it opens a share panel and my app icon is there. However if I hold down a link in Safari for a couple of seconds and the following alert pops up [image] and I tap `Share...` button then it opens a similar share panel, I see that there are Facebook and Twitter icons but my app icon is missing. Does anybody know how to make it appear there in that share panel?

This is what opens when I tap "Share..." button:

[image]

Comment: Did you add app icon in extension?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean, however if you're asking if I've enabled the app extension in Safari then yes. As I said when I use the share button everything works normally

Comment: I meant, you will add app icons in your Xcode project right? Same way you need to set app icons for Share extension in your Xcode project.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if everything has been done right or not however, again, for the usual share button everything works as expected. The app icon is displayed properly and I can open the extension by tapping it. So I assume that the icons have been set. But i think it is anyway not a question of icon itself. Without an icon it would display a defaul iOS icon, would not it?

Comment: can you add the screenshot of after clicking Share... ?

Comment: @Venkat added the screenshot

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @zisoft I did. Wait a moment. I'll provide an answer

Comment: @zisoft have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution. There's key named `NSExtensionActivationRule` in the plist of my extension. It belongs to `NSExtensionAttributes` dictionary which in its turn belongs to `NSExtension` dictionary. So the value for `NSExtensionActivationRule` looks as follows for me:

```
<string>SUBQUERY (
            extensionItems,
            $extensionItem,
            SUBQUERY (
            $extensionItem.attachments,
            $attachment,
            ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.url" ||
            ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.plain-text"
            ).@count &gt;= 1
            ).@count &gt;= 1</string>
```

As far as I remember this is `$attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.plain-text"` line which does all the magic.

The complete `NSExtension` dictionary looks as follows:

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationDictionaryVersion</key>
        <integer>2</integer>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <string>SUBQUERY (
            extensionItems,
            $extensionItem,
            SUBQUERY (
            $extensionItem.attachments,
            $attachment,
            ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.url" ||
            ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.plain-text"
            ).@count &gt;= 1
            ).@count &gt;= 1</string>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationUsesStrictMatching</key>
        <integer>2</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
    <string>MainInterface</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you post the `NSExtension` section of your info.plist in XML format? Mine looks like this: ` <key>NSExtension</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
  <dict>
   <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
   <dict>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
   </dict>
  </dict>
  <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
  <string>MainInterface</string>
  <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
  <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
 </dict>
`

Comment: Very interesting, thank you! I'll try that. I assume that `public.url` will do the trick for long press on a URL link.

Comment: it passess the link into the extension as a string. I had to turn it into url inside

Comment: ah, that makes sense. Although it's far from being obvious to look for plain text when you want to share a link...